Ender 3 S1 3D printer stops and does not respond when the nozzle heats up to 51 °C
At first I turned on the 3D printer and everything worked fine, but when the nozzle heated up to 51 degrees centigrade, the 3D printer stopped, all I could do was disconnect the printer from the network.
When I turned on the printer for the second time, everything that I described earlier was repeated.

I think we'll need much more details in order to be able to help.
